# Firestore Database - Reminder app(Flutter) - Select multiple days

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, hybrid-mobile-app

I am working on a reminder app with FLutter. Is the first time I am working with Firestore. I have checked on google but I could not find the way to do it.

I want to have the option that the reminder can be set on specific date but or multiple days. Like Monday, Saturday and Sunday.

How should I setup the database? I tried with timestamp, but is not what I want. Should be ARRAY?

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Usually you should write your answer more precise. It' hard to help you because we don't even know what you want to do with your app and the solutions depends on that.

If you need to filter the entries a lot according to those days (Mo, To, Fri) you could save them in an array to filter easy on them. Also if you want to get them together with the `document` you save in Firestore I would recommended to use an array. That way you won't need to call on a different `collection` with the days to get them. The bad side of saving in an array is that you can't just update it. You would need to download the whole array, edit it and save the whole array again. But if you just save up to 7 days of a week that won't be a big deal.

On the other side if there is no need to filter on the days and to get them together with the `document` you could save them in a separate `collection` or `subcollection` of your `document`. With this approach each day of the week would be a `document` and you could update each of them very easy and even add additional data very easy. The bad side of this approach is that you would need to call that `collection` of days separately of your event `document` and cause more reads on Firestore.

As you can see it all depends how you want your app to work and that is the reason you could not find anything on the web. Those kind of questions are to unprecise to be answered as you expect it to be. There is no silver bullet for such kind of database structures and even the same apps with same purpose could have completely different structures and work as expected.

I hope I could at least guide you to a direction so you can go the next step.